# How to edit form in bootstrap model using @included in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, forms, bootstrap-modal

I have edit form in laravel which works great in other page, but I want to edit on bootstrap modal in same page where click the edit button in any of pagination table.

is because the form page is too long codes and trying to find the way save code, the idea what i did was copy the form code after  to before  and put new page as form.blade.php my question is that how or where do i need to put #include(reseller.form) to make sure that is showing on bootstrap modal before edit it!

the edit button from pagination

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-mini" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edits" data-debitur=""><i class="fas fa-times fa-fw"></i><b>Edit</b></button>
```

modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="edits" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">




        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

form.blade.php

```
 <div class="card-body">
               <!-- Account ID -->
               <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="accountid" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Account Id:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $reseller->accountid }}" name="accountid" id="accountid" placeholder="Account ID" >
                     <div>@error('accountid')<p style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">{{$message}}</p>@enderror</div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <!-- Password -->
               <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $reseller-> password }}" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                     <div>@error('password')<p style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">{{$message}}</p>@enderror</div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <!-- Company Name -->
               <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="Company_name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Company Name:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $reseller-> companyname }}" name="companyname" id="companyname" placeholder="Company Name">
                     <div>@error('companyname')<p style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">{{$message}}</p>@enderror</div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <!-- URL -->
```

Also does any jquery involve with it to make work! please help thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a layout template you can define a Section in your layout using @yield('modals') then in your actual view you do:

```
@section('modals')
   @include('form')
@endsection
```

or simply do the @include('form') in your actual view, to display the modal you can do it via data-attributes or with jQuery event, the way you have it in your html it's fine and should display the modal on button click, if you want to use jQuery you can do:

```
$('#form').modal('toggle');
```

or

```
$('#form').modal('show');
```